# PhoneGap error handling for iOS App

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an iOS app designed in PhoneGap. The problem is that the app is crashing during my navigation through it. The app is quite big with lots of videos, but sadly I am unable to locate what instigates the error.

### What I did was:

- Safari iPad Inspect element. There are no errors there. I have removed all of them but app still crashes without any warning.
- As mentioned [here](http://www.codeitive.com/0HmVVPqjeX/error-handling-page-of-phonegap-in-ios.html), I created error.html and added these lines in `MainViewController.m`:

  ```
  (void) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error 
      {
      [theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"error" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"] isDirectory:NO]]]; 
      }
  ```

Unfortunately, neither approach worked. Any idea what direction should I go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an error tracking service that tracks JavaScript errors to get information on your errors.

[Atatus](https://www.atatus.com/)  is one such service, that works with Cordova/PhoneGap.